# How to manage text modules (boilerplates) with Sharepoint?

Tags: content-editor-web-part, content-database

I want to manage boilerplates/text modules in SharePoint.

Text modules are content snippets, which may appear on multiple sites, but are only stored once. When the source is changed, all references (where they appear) change accordingly. There might appear multiple text modules on a single SharePoint site. It should be possible to edit them in a WYSIWYG-Editor.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the enterprise version and using the publishing features, there is a list that gets created automatically called Reusable Content. This allows you to create text/html snippets that can be used in any publishing html rich text fields or added via web part.

Comment: I cannot find the button to add reusable content to a page. What are the prerequisites? I found http://community.office365.com/en-us/blogs/office_365_community_blog/archive/2012/01/30/features-of-a-sharepoint-online-publishing-site.aspx which told me to enable the publishing infrastructure feature at site level, but it did not help as the button is still missing. I use O365.

Comment: When the publishing infrastructure feature is activated, you'll see the Reusable content list at the root of the site collection. Then in the Rich Text editor, on the Insert tab there is the option for Reusable Content.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to add one thing: The button 'reusable content' remains disabled on wiki-pages, and is only enabled on publishing pages. This are the pages you have to check out to edit and which have to be 'published' to appear on the website. Also, in German, the feature you have to activate for your site collection is called "SharePoint Server Veröffentlichung" which is not a direct translation and may refuse some people (like me).

Answer (score 1):

Just put the snippets in as text or htm files in a document library and reference them from any site using a content editor web part. Use any editor than saves the format you need, theres no requirement to only use SharePoint editors.

Comment: I searched for a solution where the end-user is not required to work with files and does not need to use external software such as HTML editors. Since reusable content only supports RAW HTML, the only remaining advantage is that it's built-in. I'd prefer it if I get it working...